# how to replace invalid datatype input to "None" in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would like to replace all invalid datatype in 'number' and 'date' column. Initial table is like this:

```
name    number      date
a       1.2         123.2
b       123.2       3/13/2019
c       2.3         3/14/2019
d       569         3/15/2019
e       abc         3/15/2019
f       30          abc 
g       39.8        -3
h       3/21/2019   3/19/2019
i       -395        3/20/2019
j       4           3/21/2019
```

after cleaning, the table should like below: all invalid datatype input had been replaced by none:

```
name    number      date
a       1.2         
b       123.2       3/13/2019
c       2.3         3/14/2019
d       569         3/15/2019
e                   3/15/2019
f       30           
g       39.8        
h                   3/19/2019
i       -395        3/20/2019
j       4           3/21/2019
```

I only can replace string input with None, **i don't know how to replace number input to None in 'date' column and don't know how to replace a datetime input to None 
 in 'number' column**. if there have numeric input in datetime column or datetime input in number column, my code shows errors:

**'float' object has no attribute 'strftime'**

**The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

```
df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: None if str(type(x))=="<class 'str'>" else x)

df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

df['number'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: None if str(type(x))=="<class 'str'>" else x)
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: 'float' object has no attribute 'strftime'

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a better way but the the method that came immediately to my mind is to use regex. Here's the solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

>>>df
name    number      date
a       1.2         123.2
b       123.2       3/13/2019
c       2.3         3/14/2019
d       569         3/15/2019
e       abc         3/15/2019
f       30          abc 
g       39.8        -3
h       3/21/2019   3/19/2019
i       -395        3/20/2019
j       4           3/21/2019


# Matches m/dd/yyyy
dt_pattern = r'[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'
dt = re.compile(dt_pattern)
# alphabet strings
wd_pattern = r'[a-zA-Z]+'
wd = re.compile(wd_pattern)

df.loc[:,'date'] = [d if dt.match(str(d)) else np.nan for d in  df.loc[:, 'date']]
df.loc[:,'number'] = [d if not any([wd.match(str(d)), dt.match(str(d))]) else np.nan for d in  df.loc[:, 'number']]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

>>>df
  name number       date
0    a    1.2        NaT
1    b  123.2 2019-03-13
2    c    2.3 2019-03-14
3    d    569 2019-03-15
4    e    NaN 2019-03-15
5    f     30        NaT
6    g   39.8        NaT
7    h    NaN 2019-03-19
8    i   -395 2019-03-20
9    j      4 2019-03-21
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but i get different result as u shown, is there any line missing?

Comment: Are you able to briefly describe the differences?

Comment: name

number

date



0
a 1.2 NaT 

1
b 123.2 NaT 

2
c 2.3 NaT 

3
d 569 NaT 

4
e NaN NaT 

5
f 30 NaT 

6
g 39.8 NaT 

7
h 2019-03-21 00:00:00 NaT 

8
i -395 NaT 

9
j 4 NaT

Comment: in the number col, only string input being removed as NaN, datetime input remains.         in the date col, all had been changed to NaT

Comment: Yeah, it looks like your date formatting is different and they're not being recognized as a datetime object. How does it look like in your raw file?

Comment: I am using the exactly the same raw data:name number date
a 1.2 123.2
b 123.2 3/13/2019
c 2.3 3/14/2019
d 569 3/15/2019
e abc 3/15/2019
f 30 abc 
g 39.8 -3
h 3/21/2019 3/19/2019
i -395 3/20/2019
j 4 3/21/2019

Comment: Can you load your dataframe and then see what you get from `print(df.loc[2, 'date'])` and `print(type(df.loc[2, 'date']))`?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import re
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(excel_file,header=0,index_col=None)

print(df.loc[2, 'date'])
print(type(df.loc[2, 'date']))

Comment: 2019-03-14 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: is tat using pd.read_excel, it's automatically changed the datetime format?

Comment: Right, that's the beauty of it. Do your strings get converted to `NaT` automatically too? If they are, then you can skip that step entirely

Comment: I changed to : dt_pattern = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} 00:00:00' now it works fine, thank you for your help very much!! and thanks for your patience !!!! Appreciate a lot!!

Comment: You should also be able to check for object instance (which I'd prefer to do), instead of using regex as well. Something like `[d if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime) else np.nan for d in  df.loc[:, 'date']]`